# Cannot resolve column from input columns after second join

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to join a dataframe with 2 separate dataframes which have common parent. But I'm getting an error

This is the schema

```
            demoDf
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)

            parentDf
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

This is the scala code

```
val demoDf: Dataframe
val parentDf: DataFrame
val childDf1 = parentDf.filter(col("id") > 50)
val childDf2 = parentDf.filter(col("id") < 50)

demoDf.alias("demoDf")
    .join(childDf1.alias("childDf1"), $"demoDf.id" === $"childDf1.id")
    .join(childDf2.alias("childDf2"), $"demoDf.id" === $"childDf2.id")
```

The error I get is the following. As you can see here demoDf.id is present

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`demoDf.id`' given input columns: [demoDf.id, childDf1.id, childDf1.value, childDf2.id, childDf2.value];;
```

The expected output should be a proper join. I wonder what I'm missing. On a side note, If I simply join `childDf1` with `demoDf` it works and this error comes up only after I add second job.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using? Your code seems to work fine on spark 2.3.0.

Comment: @sachav I'm using spark version 2.3.3

Comment: Yes this works fine. But I faced this issue in an earlier Spark version. And what I did to as a workaround was - rename the joining/common column names in the second and third dataframe. So Rename the id column in "childDf1" and "childDf2" to "childId1" and "childID2" or anything similar. And it should work again.

Comment: @partha_devArch yes that works, but don't you think that is additional effort?

Comment: had ththe resulting dataframe shoulde same issue, what helped was something lime `withColumn("id",$"id")`, but no idea what the problem is. But anyway I'm wondering why you do two joins? Cant you just join `parentDf`? And, isn't your resulting dataframe empty anyways because you do two inner joins with two disjunct dataframes?

Comment: @SandeshYapuram yes it is! Either use a different spark versin, or use the work around!